# writing android drivers?

Tags: android, kernel, device-driver

I need to develop few drivers for android that should work on Android4SAM eval board.
I started writing the drivers as a normal char drivers in linux kernel, and they work as planned. whats the next step?, I didn't find any information regarding device driver porting to android, and extending the android API for those drivers.
anyone has experience with that, maybe a small tutorial or guide ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with this (pre 4.0) you need to look at the kernel the manufacturer is putting on the device (can find it on their site - usually they provide the source).  Then you can either compile your module (driver) into this and flash the phone with it or install the module on first run, this will require root privileges to do.